# Already had POJO problem while deserialize

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON but I got always the following exception:

```sh
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long) [[ObjectId: key=1, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=mypackage.B]] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][1]->mypackage.A["b"]->mypackage.B["id"])
```

The setup is easy:

```java
public class A {
    B b;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id", scope = B.class)
public class B extends SuperB {
   ...
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id", scope = SuperB.class)
public class SuperB {
    private long id;
}
```

I tried a lot of combinations of the scope parameter. But the only solution which works is to remove JsonIdentityInfo from both classes. But that would cause problems in other places.

Comment: Class B doesn't have id field, as in class SuperB id is private it will not be visible in class B

Comment: okay sorry the getter and setter are public in superB